# Django compilemessages doesn't create .mo files

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to make my django app available in French (previously it was only available in English).  I've marked a few strings in my app for translation, to try it out.  I went to the root directory of my app (where manage.py is located) and ran `django-admin.py makemessages -l fr_CA`.  This created a `django.po` file inside `myapp/locale/fr_CA/LC_MESSAGES`.  I edited that file, providing translations.  Heading back to my app's root directory, I ran `django-admin.py compilemessages -l fr_CA`.  The command returned quickly with no output to stdout.  No `.mo` file was created.

Why doesn't this create a .mo file?

I tried setting my LOCALE_PATHS in my settings file, but this had no effect (and besides, I did not need to do that to create the .po files, since they are being located in the default location, `path/to/myapp/locale`).

Answer (score 7):

Ok.  Figured it out.  For some reason, running the `compilemessages` command in the same place as I ran the `makemessages` command doesn't work, even though that's what the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#compiling-message-files) say to do!

I had to go one directory deeper -- the one which contains `settings.py` **not** the one that contains `manage.py`.  Weird.

There must be something wrong or weird with how my app is setup, since that goes plainly against what the docs say... <del>but I never changed the structure from the default...</del> Turns out I did.

Comment: I had a very similar issue, but I had to go to the app's folder (instead of the one which had `settings.py`.